# what can i do to analysis when a android img file was encrypted?

Tags: android, encryption, smartphone

I've heard that some sumsung android rom was encrypted.Usually i edit img file in a Linux operating system.It works for most mtk android phones and spreadtrum android phones.But sometimes it didn't work when a img file was encryped.  I downloaded a zenfone z5 rom from the net.Then i flash the rom in the fastboot mode and my z5 worked well.I tried to customize the rom .I mounted the xxx.img file in ubuntu and deleted some apps(those in the app file) .when i tried to repack it,errors occurred during the building.What can i do next to analysis this?Here's my scripts:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/z5# ls
make_ext4fs  simg2img  system.img.ext4  z5sys
root@ubuntu:/home/z5# df -m z5sys
Filesystem     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0          1199  1186         0 100% /home/z5/z5sys
root@ubuntu:/home/z5# ./make_ext4fs -l 1199M -s -a system system.img ./z5sys
Creating filesystem with parameters:
    Size: 1257242624
    Block size: 4096
    Blocks per group: 32768
    Inodes per group: 7680
    Inode size: 256
    Journal blocks: 4796
    Label: 
    Blocks: 306944
    Block groups: 10
    Reserved block group size: 79
error: do_inode_allocate_extents: Failed to allocate 5168 blocks
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about analysing an "encrypted" Android ROM and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase BOARD_SYSTEMIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE inside BoardConfig.mk